# Open set in product topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that I have a given set $M$ and want to determine its interior, let me say e.g. 
$$ M=\{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\mid f(0) \in (-1,1) \text{ and } f(1)>1\}\;.$$

In my opinion this set is already open and therefore its own interior as $(-1,1)$ is an open interval $(1,\infty)$ too and since there is no restriction for all the other points these points are open too, as $\mathbb{R}$ is open. Am I right?

Comment: Your set $M$ is a subset of a mapping space, that is, the space of real maps. Do you know something about compact open topology?

Comment: a few things, what are you referring to?

Comment: I'm not sure but decide if a subset of a mapping space is an open set is not so trivial.

Comment: What topology are you endowing the mapping space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} = \{f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \;|\; f \text{ is continuous}\}$ with?  Once you specify *that*, we can talk about whether $M$ is open.

Comment: f does not have to be continuous. I am regarding the product topology of $\mathbb{R}$, where the metric of the reals is the euclidean metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right. This set is open and thus it's its own interior.

Comment: may i ask what would happen if i have more than finite conditions on my function with open sets. for example that at each natural number the value of f has to be an element of (0,1). in this case the set should not be open as there are more than finite restriciton. but what is the interior? could you explain this to me too?

Comment: @Lipschitz I think that should be asked as a separate question. But first you should try and see if you can write it as a union of sets with only finitely many coordinates restricted.

Comment: maybe if i declare a function that maps from all real numbers without the natural ones to the reals and then choose finitely many naturals with images in (0,1). a union over all possible ones will give me the set. but this would mean that my set was originally open as the set is equal to its interior, so where am i wrong?